# Can not load core data in a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview

I am doing a Karaoke project. I want to load my data to a table view using NSManagedObjectModel but It didnt work

Firstly, I load all songs in my KBDataInitializer.m and it work fine. I can push them to an array. I also can NSlog all songs name.

```
@implementation KBDataInitializer

- (NSArray*) getAllSongs{

    [self setupDataContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc ] initWithEntityName:@"KBSong"];
    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *songs = [self.dataContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];

    if (fetchError !=NULL){
        NSLog(@"fetch data ERROR");
    }
      return songs;
}
```

BUT when I load each song to the tableview in my HomeController it display nothing and when I  try to  NSlog my variable *song it show an message (which mean they can not load data):

```
$3 = 0x0e483d90 <KBSong: 0xe483d90> (entity: KBSong; id: 0x818b630 <x-coredata://4BA983BA-1914-47C9-A22B-0373E84EAFC8/KBSong/p1> ; data: <fault>)

However in my viewDidLoad() I can load all songs.
```

My code in HomeController.h

```
@interface KBHomeController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *songs;
}
@end
```

This is my loading code in my table view in HomeController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    KBDataInitializer *data = [[KBDataInitializer alloc]init];

    //Use for import updated new Songs
    //[data importData];

    songs = [data getAllSongs];

    // This one works fine
    for (KBSong *song in songs)
    {
        NSLog(song.name);
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    KBSong *song = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = song.name;
    return cell;
}
```

This is my KBSong.h

```
@interface KBSong : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * composer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * language;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lyric;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * volume;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * favorite;

@end
```

Comment: can you please just try once by doing    NSString *tempString = song.name;  then cell.textlabel.text = tempString; and then told me if you still getting the error. if this will solve your problem then i will explain this to you

Comment: I did it but the result was still the same :(. I "po song" and it display  "...data: <fault>". It is weird that my songs array still had 1000 objects but I can not push each object to my  *song variable.

Comment: From where did comes songs in KBSong *song = [songs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: can you send me your code at anurag.soni@psit.in for better understanding of your work flow

Comment: Could it be that  your managedObjectContext is released. How have you used managedObjectContext

Comment: Where did you call getAllSongs method?

Comment: Hi all, this is the link to download my project. Plz help me solve the problem thank u :) https://app.box.com/s/kch7pnl91v7mot22mvzm

Comment: your code doessn't have sqlitemanager.m and .h please upload it again

Comment: Oh I'm sorry this is the new link https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_10836105647

Comment: $3 = 0x0e483d90 <KBSong: 0xe483d90> (entity: KBSong; id: 0x818b630 <x-coredata://4BA983BA-1914-47C9-A22B-0373E84EAFC8/KBSong/p1> ; data: <fault>)

That isn't an error message. `fault` means, that the data weren't loaded yet. Please post more relevant code in your questions. I won't create a account, just to see your code.  
Anyway: questions and answers should be always complete without the need of downloading something.

Comment: that 's all relevant code I can show u . This link you dont need to register to download https://app.box.com/s/v5zwejdt1e7lm12vhx5m

Comment: That is not all relevant code. wheere are the tableview delegate and data source methods? where are the codes about the core data stack. your question needs to be complete to be valid on stack overflow. voting for close.

Comment: Hi, This problem here is very simple, I use NSmanagedObjectContext to load my data in sqlite. I load them to an *songs array and can NSLog it in viewDidLoad() but in Tableview:mycellForRowAtIndexPath my data in array *songs was gone. I am newbie and I spent few days but can not fix it. If anyone know the solution please help me, If you dont know or dont want to help plz leave it, dont close my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you got all your memory management wrong.

First of all, allocating an object and putting it to a local variable will make the object disappear after the method ends.
So after the end of your

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

method your

```
KBDataInitializer *data = ...
```

is already out of scope again. Together with it, the

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *dataContext;
```

is gone.

Second, the songs are

```
@interface KBSong : NSManagedObject
```

which makes them dependent on their NSManagedObjectContext.

These are the basics, the short way to fix your current problem is:

KBHomeController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KBDataInitializer;

@interface KBHomeController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *songs;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) KBDataInitializer *data;

@end
```

KBHomeController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.data = [[KBDataInitializer alloc]init];

    //Use for import updated new Songs
    [self.data importData];

    songs = [self.data getAllSongs];

...
}
```

But this only helps with your current problem. To understand what you did wrong, read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html . And http://www.raywenderlich.com/2657/memory-management-tutorial-for-ios . And http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1 . Plus their follow ups.
All of it. And also try to understand it.

Also please note I would use a [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that task.